# Typescript can't pass translations as Input

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I have an array (`foo`) which I want to initialize and then pass it on as `@Input` in a child module.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  foo = [{
    name: 'NAME', desc: this.translate.get('description')
   }];

 constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  translate.setDefaultLang('hu'); //edit (forgot to copy this line here)
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <app-home [data]='foo'></app-home>
```

**app.home.ts**

```
 export class AppHome {
   @Input data: any;
 }
```

**app.home.html**

```
<h1>{{data.name}}</h1>
<h1>{{data.desc}}</h1>
```

I expect the name and description in my translations to get displayed however nothing gets displayed, not even an error.

EDIT: Making `foo` a single object instead of an array printed out some values but the translations are still not working [object Object] is returned instead of descriptions.

Comment: foo is an array. you want foo to be an object

Comment: In the example I provided I have only one object however in the complete example i have an array of multiple objects.. nevermind.. sorry and thanks.. see the edit :D

Comment: do you use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for translation? Then the get function returns Observable<string>. So use `<h1>{{data.desc | async}}</h1>`

Comment: this returns the name of the key, but how do I get the value of it ?

Comment: it returns the key if no translation was found. check if there are translations available for the key.

Comment: this is my json file: {
    "description" : "test this string as the description"
}. and I can tell that the reading is okay because the simple translations work just fine :/

Comment: please provide a minimal stackblitz example.

Comment: https://angular-wf9nvt.stackblitz.io or https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wf9nvt?file=src%2Fassets%2Fi18n%2Fhu.json i don't know which one im supposed to share :D :))

Comment: all working fine. the only problem is that the initialization of foo is done before the language is set. You must add the language and then initialize foo: [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x99jjs).
You can use APP_INITIALIZER Factory to set the language before and component is loaded

Comment: @A.Winnen I can't change the language though :/.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wf9nvt?file=src%2Fassets%2Fi18n%2Fro.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Custom component**

```
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
    @Component({
      selector: "app-date-picker",
      templateUrl: "./date-picker.component.html"
    })

    export class DatePickerComponent extends BaseComponentHelpers {
      @Input() placeholderText: string;

      constructor(
        public fb: FormBuilder,
        private translateService: TranslateService
      ) {
        super();
      }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
<app-date-picker
              #currentDocumentDate
              [placeholderText]="'invoice.DOCUMENT_DATE' | translate"></app-date-picker>
```